# Why "Sleep well" after sleep?

Tags: tenses

I heard protagonists say "Sleep well?" after sleep in a movie and got curious; why is it "Sleep well", not "Slept well"? Shouldn't it be "Slept well"? Since they are not about to sleep, but already have slept. Is *Did you* removed from "Did you sleep well"?

Comment: You could **also** say “Slept well?”, but it is more common to ask an underlyingly full question, “Did you sleep well?” and then just contract or leave out _did you_. This pattern is marked as highly conversational/colloquial, but it works for a lot of similar questions: “(did you) have a nice day?”, “(did you) get off work early?”, “(did you) ever think about that?”, etc.

Comment: "You looking at me, @Janus. You looking at me?"

Comment: @DavidPugh That too—though in that case, it’s only the verb (‘are’) that’s being left out, not the entire subject–auxiliary cluster.

Comment: @DavidPugh: You mean "You talking to me?"

Comment: @Janus & Area: With my feet planted firmly in the 12th century, I am not at my best on modern popular culture. I think I managed to hybridise Taxi Driver with Casablanca; I shall go fall on my sword.

Comment: @DavidPugh: "Here's talking to you, David" :)

Comment: Why are you happy that "have you" is erased from "Have you slept well?" but not "did you" from "Did you sleep well?"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is *Did you* removed from "Did you sleep well"?

Yes, exactly. The speaker's intonation ought to convey the intention that this is a question rather than an imperative. One would also say "Sleep well" before someone goes to sleep, but in that case the intonation would be different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an elision. We could perfectly well ask, "slept well?" instead but don't always.

Comment: I thought elision was for dropping syllables. Isn't dropping words called reduction?

Comment: @Area: You may have got me, depending on what the big boys say. I will confess to you that while my sense of usage is pretty good, I don't always know the correct linguistics terms for what I know. I am like that guy in the Moliere play who discovered that he had been speaking "prose" all his life.

Comment: I just know what the movies taught me. This term was used in 'Outsourced', where the lead tells his Indian colleagues to use 'reductions' because that's how Americans talk.